# how to declare a block and a subblock in a specific CMS page?

Tags: blocks, cms, static-block

i have a CMS page with content

```
      {{block type="core/template" name="cms.man" template="cms/man.phtml"}}
```

How could i add a reference block / sub-block to this block so i can add a captcha to this man.phtml form?

Comment: you add a block in layout in cms page

Comment: how can i make it called by just one cms page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Admin panel `CMS->pages->your page`

Then goto `design Tab` you can change the layout from the layout list.

If you want to remove the side bar

write the below code in **Layout Update XML**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="cms.man" template="cms/man.phtml">
        <block type="core/template" name="another.block" template="cms/another.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Cheers